# Python : Login to Website using logged windows user

Tags: python-3.x, single-sign-on

What i am looking for: 
1. Login to a website.
2. Use user credentials automatically from logged-in user.
3. Store cookies/token and use it for subsequent call to website.

So basically, as these days most organization has SSO enabled so once you logged in your system, you can access the organization internal websites through browser without manual entry of user/password.

Is there any way, we can achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

best way i can thing to do this is to use the requests library to login to the website using the given credentials and then store the cookies in a database.
look for the requests library docs for more detailed answers.

[login](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post)

[cookies](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies)

Comment: Thanks, yes i am aware of that but i dont want to provide any credentials explicitly. It should be taken automatically from logged users.